# Getting error while integrating paytm to laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, paytm

I have installed laravel package for the payment gateway of Paytm. I have added the correct credentials but I am getting invalid: This MID is not available on our staging environment error.

i don't understand why is it happening.

```
 'paytm-wallet' => [
        'env' => env('PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT'), // values : (local | production)
        'merchant_id' => env('PAYTM_MERCHANT_ID'),
        'merchant_key' => env('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY'),
        'merchant_website' => env('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE'),
        'channel' => env('PAYTM_CHANNEL'),
        'industry_type' => env('PAYTM_INDUSTRY_TYPE'),
    ],
```

Solution to the problem.

Comment: You will need another MID for your staging environment, you cannot use the same as your prod one. https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys?src=dev

Comment: @Aless55 Sir i have enabled test mode. Staging environment and test mode are different ? do I need to configure more in paytm dashboard.